# Android custom LinearLayout

Tags: android, custom-view

I a little bit stuck. I try to create custom LinearLayout and work with its childs defined in the xml file.

```
    class MyRadioGroup @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0
    ) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    
        init {
           
            val c = childCount //always 0
            
        }
}
```

and xml that use my class

```
<SomeViewGroup>
    <MyRadioGroup>
       <View/>
       <View/>
    </MyRadioGroup>
 </SomeViewGroup>
```

How can i get the views defined in xml file in MyRadioGroup?

Answer (score 0):

well, the problem was, when the class will know about its childs. when i try to get the child's in method

```
onfinishInflate
```

they was there